# Problema al insertar una imagen con tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

¡Hola! ¡Espero que estén bien! Estoy estudiando programación autodidacticamemte, actualmente estudio python y estoy con las interfaces gráficas, estoy utilizando la librería tkinter. Me ha surgido un problema el cual es el siguiente. Cuando intento insertar una imagen me da un error! 
Este es mi código:

```
from tkinter import * 

ventana = Tk()

Myframe = Frame()

Myframe.pack()

Imagen=Photo(file="logo.png")

Imagen_2 =Label(Myframe, Image=Imagen)

Imagen_2.place(x=100, y=200)

ventana.mainloop()
```

nota: si tengo la imagen en el mismo directorio que el script, he intentado todo pero no me funciona!

Python version 3.6.0

Comment: Josue, nos podrías indicar cual es el error que tienes? De paso también sería bueno que aclararás de que módulo se obtiene **Photo**.

Comment: Gracias por responder a mi pregunta, ya solucione el error, lo de Photo fue que no complete la clase PhotoImage, error de principiante. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema desde un mac no me deja insertar imagenes `import tkinter as tk from tkinter import ttk, Frame, PhotoImage #creamos objeto de la clase tkinter ventana = tk.Tk() #tamaño ancho = 500 alto = 400 tamaño = str(ancho)+"x"+str(alto) ventana.geometry(tamaño) #titulo ventana.title('Imagen en Frame') #icono ventana.iconbitmap('icono.ico') # creamos el frame frame = Frame(ventana) #posicionamos frame.pack(padx=10, pady=10) frame.config(bg='lightblue') frame.config(width=400,height=300) frame.config(cursor="pirate") #arrow frame.config(relief="sunken") #ridge frame.config(bd=25) #

Answer (score 1):

```
from tkinter import * 
#ventana 
ventana = Tk()
#el frame debe posicionarse en...si lo colocas vació es tenerlo en memoria pero no pasa a ser mostrado 
Myframe = Frame(ventana)

Myframe.pack(fill="both",expand=True)

Imagen=PhotoImage(file="logo.png")
#la mayoria de las palabras reservadas por el lenguaje o una libreria deben ser respetadas tenias "Image=Imagen" y lo correcto  "image=variable(en este caso Imagen)"
Imagen_2 =Label(Myframe, image=Imagen)

Imagen_2.place(x=0, y=0)

ventana.mainloop()
```